# Why was ancestor imprisoned in Bodmin Gaol?

Tags: 19th-century, england, cornwall, imprisonment, criminal-records

I have located my 3rd times Great Grandfather in Bodmin Gaol from Ancestry records but no details of why he was there.  I have the following information and would be grateful if you were able to let me know any details of why he was imprisoned.

David Tabb. Age 45. Butcher. Born abt 1791 in St.Columb Major.  He was admitted July 1834 and discharged Jul 1836.  He may have been because he could not pay a debt. Registration No. 2597. Volume Number AD 1676/5/1. CRO Class Number. AD 1676/5/1.

Comment: Hi Diane, welcome. I've just made some formatting and tag edits and also removed your signature since it automatically appears beneath your post.

Comment: Thank you Harry.  I thought about my name after I sent it.

Comment: There is a published list of [Debtors imprisoned in Cornwall County Gaol at Bodmin](http://www.worldcat.org/title/debtors-imprisoned-in-cornwall-county-gaol-at-bodmin-in-the-years-1831-1853-and-1868-1879/oclc/271468774) by Sally J. Pocock, covering the years 1831-1853.

Comment: There are some similar questionns her eyou might find useful to read if you haven't done so already: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cornwall+imprisonment

Comment: Thank you to sempaiscuba and ColeValley Girl for letting me know this information.

Answer (score 4):

There is a report of the case in the Royal Cornwall Gazette (15th Nov 1834) and concerns debt of £400-£500 by obtaining cattle from farmers on credit. The court *"considered this a very fraudulent case and directed the insolvent to be remanded in order to his producing a fair debtor and creditor account ..."*

Comment: Just to add: the full article can be found on the [British Newspaper Archive](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/viewer/bl/0000177/18341115/006/00020), which is a for-pay site (but new accounts can get a few pages for free). The article notes Tabb's largest debt as £95, which may match a "Debt: 95" entry in the Ancestry record.

Comment: Thank you to Antony and Andy for this helpful information. Very much appreciated.